# feeding several txt files to an executable to process in unix

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to feed my executable file a series of text files.
I'm testing this with my executable file doing a simple word count.
This type of thing works fine for one file:

```
while (cin << word){
  count++;
}
```

...and in the shell...

```
prog.exe < quickbrownfox.txt
```

gives me a word count of 9 as it should

> the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy log

has 9 words in it.

How do I feed my program several text files, one after the other?

like:

```
prog.exe < qbf.txt abc.txt file 3.txt file4.txt...etc
```

Comment: Do you want a total word count on them, or word count for every file? If the first just pipe output of cat command to it: `cat qbf.txt abc.txt file3.txt file4.txt | prog.exe`      BTW In unix land you have `prog.exe`?

Comment: You can write your program to open each file in the argument list in turn, defaulting to reading standard input if there are no files in the argument list.  This is a time-honoured way of working (think of tools like `grep`, `sed`, `wc`, etc).  It isn't dreadfully hard, either.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [cat](https://www.google.com.au/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?cat&ei=gyFOUpOOJufUigemoYAY&usg=AFQjCNFSzYAc45KULutPXTCllDywqEeKGA&sig2=hk3Mllw_jlU3WN4fl2dhdA&bvm=bv.53537100,d.aGc) command to see if it does what you want.

```
cat qbf.txt abc.txt file3.txt file4.txt | prog.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the file name and/or word count in individual files, you should use a loop.  For example:

```
for file in qbf.txt abc.txt file 3.txt file4.txt
do
    echo "$file `prog.exe < $file`"
done
```

Comment: Why not use `wc -w` to count the words in a file?

Comment: Depending on the file names in that folder, the OP could use `*.txt` too... @JL This is a simplified example of feeding several files to his program... The count is just for testing.

Answer (score 0):

Write the filenames in a file, and run the following command

```
cat filename.list
file1
file2
file3
...

cat filenames.list | xargs prog.exe
```

the command above will execute your program with each argument piped from stdout. xargs will avoid the argument number limit in case the list contains several lines.